# Is it possible to detect nearby iOS devices that don't have my app?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Title sums it up pretty well, but here is some background:

I have looked into CoreBluetooth and MultipeerConnectivity for detecting nearby devices in Swift, but there is one problem: they only detect devices with my app installed, since my app calls for the device to begin advertising.

After significant googling, I am unable to find a way to detect all nearby iPhones. I am able to detect nearby Bluetooth devices, such as Apple Watches, Speakers, and Nest Cameras, but other iOS devices do not show up.

It must be possible, however, because AirDrop is able to detect nearby devices. So why is a third-party iOS app unable to, or is there a way to do it?

All help appreciated, thanks!

**TL;DR** looking for a way to detect nearby iOS devices without my app installed, like AirDrop does.

Comment: Bump, have you been able to figure this out?