# How can I find the list of all available nearby devices, even if they don't have my app?

Tags: swift

Follow up for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62868173/is-it-possible-to-detect-nearby-ios-devices-that-dont-have-my-app) from Jul. 2020. I want to know if it's possible to programmatically **access the total list and number of available devices around me**, even if they don't have the same app installed; similar to what AirDop does.

I've looked at Peer To Peer, Nearby Interactions, Bonjour framework and all of them require the same app to be downloaded.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that since all mentioned frameworks need to run same type of session with another devices, which is (currently) impossible without an app.